# Формула в Google Sheets (excel)

Tags: excel, google-docs

Добрый день,

Исходные статистические данные:  
1. колонка A содержит имена героев (имена могут повторяться);  
2. колонка B содержит результат (победа или поражение, w и l).

**Задача:**
Подсчитать кол-во побед и поражений для уникального героя.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MS2ca9dEJwcYDo7xPPMdxr3cXTmqJZdusolTAC673YE/edit?usp=sharing

Заранее благодарю

Answer (score 1):

Нужно использовать COUNTIFS

```
Синтаксис: =countifs(criteria_range1;criteria1;[criteria_range2];[criteria2]...)
```

`criteria_range1` - диапазон 1, в котором проверять выполнение условия 1
`criteria1` - условие 1
`criteria_range2, 3, ...` - диапазон 2, 3 и т.д., в котором проверять условия 2, 3 и т.д. соответственно
`criteria2, 3, ...` - условия 2, 3

```
=COUNTIFS (A:A,F2, B:B,"w")  
=COUNTIFS (A:A,F2, B:B,"l")
```